# How to install subdirectories to different locations with CMake?

Tags: installation, cmake

I have a couple of CMake projects which have their own install logic defined. Now, I want to add a global CMakeLists.txt that adds those projects using `add_subdirectory()` in order to build and install all of them at once. How can I provide a different `${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}` to each of them from the outside?

What I tried is changing the install prefix between the calls to add the subdirectories but they are installed when actually calling `make install` and at that time, the install prefix is already set to the last assigned value.

Comment: If your projects have different install logic, you shouldn't build them using `add_subdirectory` within single global project. Instead, global project may install them using CMake call either via `execute_process` or `ExternalProject_Add`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Could you provide an example of how that would look like, please? I think using `execute_process` would mean that I can't specify dependent targets between those subdirectories anymore, right? Moreover, the command output can only be displayed after the full comman has finished which is a bit annoying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your subprojects require same variable to have different values(at global scope) you cannot build them using `add_subdirectory` within single global project.

Instead, global project may install them using `cmake` call either via `execute_process` or `ExternalProject_Add`. Sometimes, `install(SCRIPT)` command may be used for that.

---

**Installing using `execute_process`** makes subproject available immediately at `configuration` stage.

It can be used when subproject has some packaging mechanism (see [CMake tutorials about packaging](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Tutorials#CMake_Packages)), so global object may execute  `find_package(<subproject-name>)` and link with libraries, defined in subproject, in the most simple way(using variables, filled outside).

```
# Configure subproject into <subproject-build-dir>
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -D<var>=<value> <subproject-source-dir> 
    WORKING_DIRECTORY <subproject-build-dir>)
# Build and install subproject
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build <subproject-build-dir> --target install)
# Extract variables, related to subproject for link with it.
find_package(<subproject-name>)

# Create target in global project and link with subproject
include_directories(${<subproject-name>_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${<subproject-name>_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_executable(global_program main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(global_program ${<subproject-name>_LIBRARIES})
```

---

**Installing using `ExternalProject_add`** assigns target to the subproject, which will be installed at `build` stage. Linking with subproject in that case is also possible, but requires to fill variables manually.

```
# Configure, build and install subproject
ExternalProject_Add(<subproject_target>
    SOURCE_DIR <subproject-source-dir>
    CMAKE_CACHE_ARGS -D<var>=<value>
    BINARY_DIR <subproject-build-dir>
    INSTALL_DIR <CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX-for-subproject>
    )

# Create target in global project and link with subproject
include_directories(<subproject-include-files-location>)
link_directories(<subproject-libraries-location>)
add_executable(global_program main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(global_program <subproject-libraries-name>)
# Make sure that subproject will be built before executable.
add_dependencies(global_program <subproject_target>)
```

---

**Installing using `install(SCRIPT)`** executes script at `install` stage. This approach can be used when there is no build-dependencies between global project and subproject.

*subproject_install.cmake:*

```
# Configure subproject into <subproject-build-dir>
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -D<var>=<value> <subproject-source-dir> 
    WORKING_DIRECTORY <subproject-build-dir>)
# Build and install subproject
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build <subproject-build-dir> --target install)
```

*CMakeLists.txt:*

```
install(SCRIPT subproject_install.cmake)
```

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer. I'd like to use CMake to generate makefiles or project files that I can use to build the whole project again after changing the code. When using `execute_process()` the subdirectories will be built at configuration time, so I have to re-run CMake after making source changes. Even with a way to execute the second `execute_process()` call at build time, I would be back to the problem of dependency libraries that need to be installed before depending targets are even configured. Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: If you can modify subproject, you better fix it to use common install logic, so you will be able to use `add_subdirectory` for it. Direct installing of subproject, described in my answer, implies that you treat it as persistent.

Comment: I realized that the question I posted as a comment here is not strictly related to this one, so I [created a new post for it](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31755870/1079110). Would be nice if you could check it out.

Comment: @ruslo: This is just a pattern, not a full code. Of course, real application needs error checking to be performed.