# How to use libraries within my CMake project that need to be installed first?

Tags: cmake, build-system

I have a problem with my CMake build system. There are `CMakeLists.txt` files defining runtimes or libraries or using `ExternalProjects_Add()` to download and build external code. Because of dependencies, those projects have to find each other. Now I want to have a `CMakeLists.txt` at the top level that builds all those at once. In order to find a project, is must be installed. But finding projects is already done at configuration time in CMake.

```
repository
├─project
│ ├─game (Depends on engine, uses EngineConfig.cmake once installed)
│ │ ├─CMakeLists.txt
│ │ ├─include
│ │ ├─src
│ │ └─textures
│ ├─engine (Depends on boost, uses built-in FindBoost.cmake)
│ │ ├─CMakeLists.txt
│ │ ├─include
│ │ └─src
│ ├─boost (Not the source code, just an ExternalProject_Add call)
│ : └─CMakeLists.txt
│
├─build
│ ├─game
│ ├─engine
│ ├─boost (Source will be downloaded and built here)
│ : ├─download
│   ├─source
│   :
│
├─install
│ ├─game
│ │ ├─bin
│ │ └─textures
│ ├─engine
│ │ ├─include
│ │ │ └─engine
│ │ │   ├─EngineConfig.cmake (Needed to find the library)
│ │ │   :
│ │ │
│ │ └─lib
│ ├─boost (Layout is up to the external library)
│ : └─ ...
│
└─CMakeLists.txt (Calls add_subdirectory for all inside the project folder)
```

**Run a CMake process for every project:** Using `execute_process(${CMAKE_COMMAND} ...)`, I can configure and build each project after another at configure time. However, this means I always have to run CMake after editing the code and cannot compile from within the IDE I generated project files for.

**Linking to CMake targets:** Running a CMake process for all external libraries is okay since I don't work on them. My own libraries could be used by calling `target_link_libraries()` with their target names. However, linking isn't enough. My libraries include directories of external libraries. Those must be made available to the using project, as well.

How can I use libraries within my CMake project that need to be installed first?

Comment: `My own libraries could be used by calling target_link_libraries() with their target names. However, linking isn't enough...` - could you add example for that usage, based on project hierarchy you give?

Comment: Sure, for example *game* wants to use *engine*. `project/engine/CMakeListst.txt` declares the library using `add_library(engine ${SOURCE_FILES})`. Then, `project/game/CMakeListst.txt` declares its executable with `add_runtime(game ${SOURCE_FILES})` and links the library to it with `target_link_libraries(game engine)`. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can classify your projects into three groups:

1. External dependencies you are not working on in this super-project
2. Projects you're working on but are too complex to add them as a subdirectory, for example having too many targets or other reasons. (You don't seem to have such a project in your example.)
3. Projects you're working on: these will be added as a subdirectory of the super-project.

You need to configure, build and install the project in groups #1 and #2 before configuring the super-project:

- You can do it before running the super-project's `CMakeLists.txt`, for example, from a shell-script
- Or, as you mentioned, from within the super-project's `CMakeLists.txt`, using `execute_process(${CMAKE_COMMAND} ...)`. You can do it conditionally using the result of an appropriate `find_package(... QUIET)` command.

You need to decide if projects in group #3, like `engine` will be used solely in projects that uses them as subdirectories or you intend to use them as standalone libraries, built in their own build trees.

Also, you mentioned that: *"My libraries include directories of external libraries"*. Let's cover all such possible libraries the `engine` can be dependent on:

- say, `LIB1` and `LIB2` are private and public external dependencies of `engine` and their config-modules export old-school `LIB1_*` and `LIB2_*` variables
- `LIB3` and `LIB4` are private and public external dependencies of `engine` and their config-modules export the `LIB3` and `LIB4` *imported* libraries

By public and private dependencies I mean whether the particular library is used or not used on the interface of `engine`.

Now, if `engine` is to be used only as a subdirectory then the relevant section of `engine/CMakeLists.txt` is:

```
add_library(engine ...)
target_include_directories(engine
    PRIVATE
        ${LIB1_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    PUBLIC
        $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
        ${LIB2_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_compiled_definitions(engine
    PRIVATE ${LIB1_DEFINITIONS}
    PUBLIC ${LIB2_DEFINITIONS})
target_link_libraries(engine
    PRIVATE LIB3
    PUBLIC LIB4)
```

in `repository/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
add_subdirectory(engine)
add_subdirectory(game)
```

in `game/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
add_executable(game ...)
target_link_libraries(game engine)
```

The include dirs of both of the engine and of its public dependencies will be correctly forwarded to `game`.

If `engine` will also be built in its own build tree (in another project) you need to add the exporting code to `engine/CMakeLists.txt` and maybe a custom config-module that calls `find_package` (or `find_dependency`) for its dependencies. See [How to use CMake to find and link to a library using install-export and find_package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31537602/how-to-use-cmake-to-find-and-link-to-a-library-using-install-export-and-find-pac/31537603#31537603) for details. One issue not discussed in that answer is finding the dependencies of a library in the library's config module:

The referenced SO answer simply installs the `<lib>-targets.cmake` script, generated by the `install(EXPORT ...)` command, as the config-module:

```
install(EXPORT engine-targets
    FILE engine-config.cmake
    DESTINATION lib/cmake/engine)
```

This solution is fine when `engine` has no further dependencies. If it does, they need to be found at the beginning of the config module, which should be written manually.

`engine/engine-config.cmake:`

```
include(CMakeFindDependencyMacro)
find_dependency(some-dep-of-engine)
include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/engine-targets.cmake)
```

and in `engine/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
install(EXPORT engine-targets
    FILE engine-targets.cmake
    DESTINATION lib/cmake/engine)
install(FILES engine-config.cmake
    DESTINATION lib/cmake/engine)
```

*Note: The `CMakeFindDependencyMacro` has been introduced in CMake 3.0. With an older CMake you can use `find_package` instead of `find_dependency` (handling of QUIET and REQUIRED options will not be forwarded to the dependency).*

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. After working on my build system for the last week, I got a better understanding of your answer. Could you elaborate on your last paragraph, please? `engine` is the main library of my project and `game` is just a demo to test features. It's intended that other people can use `engine` for real games.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. After working on my build system for the last week, I got a better understanding of your answer. Could you elaborate on your last paragraph, please? `engine` is the main library of my project and `game` is just a demo to test features. It's intended that other people can use `engine` for real games. Also, are the `target_` functions the new way to write find and configure scripts?

Comment: @danijar: I extended my answer, I referenced another answer which discusses this question. Let me know if you need any further info. The `target_*` commands are new ways (they're 2 years old) to specify the requirements (include dirs, compile options, link libs) of a target. The `install(EXPORT ...)` command can be used to write config-modules, it just got much more convenient with the introduction of the new `target_*` commands.

Comment: Is there a way to not write `find_dependency` in the config file manually? Is it possible to do it via CMakeLists automatically?

Comment: No, there's no automatic way to do that.

Comment: @tamas.kenez Can you please answer this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57879647/cmake-build-and-install-shared-library-from-subdirectory-before-building-main-di ? `target_link_libraries(game engine)` seems to be statically linking the engine library, right? What if I want to dynamically link the shared library `engine.so`?

Answer (score 4):

When export library from `engine` project you need to specify its include directories. Code below is a simplification of example provided at http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-packages.7.html#creating-packages. Paths are adjasted for use installation prefix `install/engine` for build and install `engine` component.

engine/CMakeLists.txt:

```
...
install(TARGETS engine EXPORT engineTargets
    DESTINATION lib
    INCLUDES DESTINATION include
)

set(ConfigPackageLocation lib/cmake/engine)

install(EXPORT engineTargets
    FILE EngineTargets.cmake
    DESTINATION ${ConfigPackageLocation}
)

install(FILES cmake/EngineConfig.cmake
    DESTINATION ${ConfigPackageLocation}
)
```

engine/cmake/EngineConfig.cmake:

```
include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/EngineTargets.cmake")
```

This provides *interface* of the exported target. So when it will be linked by executable, the executable gets proper `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` property:

CMakeLists.txt:

```
# Need for `find_package` to find `EngineConfig.cmake`.
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH <path-pointed-to-install/engine>)
```

game/CMakeLists.txt:

```
find_package(Engine)
add_executable(game ...)
target_link_libraries(game engine)
```

Comment: Could you show how to import it inside `game/CMakeLists.txt` as well, please?

Comment: I have added import and export code into my answer. Actually, it is based on example at http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-packages.7.html#creating-packages.

Comment: Thanks. I think I understand these steps and will try them later today. However, won't I get an error at `find_package` when configuring the top-level project as `EngineConfig.cmake` is only available after building the project?

Comment: You install `engine` using `execute_process`, are you? If so, `EngineConfig.cmake` will be available immediately after that command.

Comment: I want to use add_subdirectory() otherwise I have to re-generate project files every time I change *engine* which means restarting the IDE. I work on both *engine* and *game* and not on *external*.

Comment: Basically, I need to find libraries at compile time. Also, assuming all projects would be (magically) build and installed once, it would be fine. The find scripts would find what they need and building the top-level project would update all installed files in the right order so that *game* would use the updated *engine* library.

Comment: You write "My libraries include directories of external libraries." in you question. If you use `add_subdirectory`, exporting is not needed at all, `find_package()` call is not needed too. Setting include directories in `engine/CMakeLists.txt` as `target_include_directories(engine PUBLIC include)` and linking in `game/CMakeLists.txt` as `target_link_libraries(game engine)` automatically include directory `engine/include` for game.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [@Tsyvarev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3440745/tsyvarev) and [@tamas.kenez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3590849/tamas-kenez) you for the two good answers. I ended up using the [super-build pattern](http://cmake.3232098.n2.nabble.com/Superbuild-subprojects-and-find-package-td7584088.html). The top-level project doesn't do much at configure time. At build time, it runs external CMake processes to configure, build and install the projects.

Usually, this is implemented using `ExternalProject_Add()` instead of `add_subdirectory()` to add the projects. I found `add_custom_command()` to work better since it doesn't do additional tasks in the background like creating stamp files and so on.

```php
# add_project(<project> [DEPENDS project...])
function(add_project PROJECT)
    cmake_parse_arguments(PARAM "" "" "DEPENDS" ${ARGN})
    add_custom_target(${PROJECT} ALL DEPENDS ${PARAM_DEPENDS})
    # Paths for this project
    set(SOURCE_DIR  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${PROJECT})
    set(BUILD_DIR   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT})
    set(INSTALL_DIR ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/${PROJECT})
    # Configure
    escape_list(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH)
    escape_list(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH)
    add_custom_command(TARGET ${TARGET}
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND}
            --no-warn-unused-cli
            "-DCMAKE_MODULE_PATH=${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH_ESCAPED}"
            "-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH_ESCAPED}"
            -DCMAKE_BINARY_DIR=${BUILD_DIR}
            -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${INSTALL_DIR}
            -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}
            ${SOURCE_DIR}
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${BUILD_DIR})
    # Build
    add_custom_command(TARGET ${TARGET}
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND}
            --build .
            --target install
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${BUILD_DIR})
    # Help later find_package() calls
    append_global(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${INSTALL_DIR})
endfunction()
```

Here are the two helper functions. It took me quite some time to figure out the right way to pass list parameters to other CMake processes without them being interpreted and passes as multiple parameters.

```php
# escape_list(<list-name>)
function(escape_list LIST_NAME)
    string(REPLACE ";" "\;" ${LIST_NAME}_ESCAPED "${${LIST_NAME}}")
    set(${LIST_NAME}_ESCAPED "${${LIST_NAME}_ESCAPED}" PARENT_SCOPE)
endfunction()

# append_global(<name> value...)
function(append_global NAME)
    set(COMBINED "${${NAME}}" "${ARGN}")
    list(REMOVE_DUPLICATES COMBINED)
    set(${NAME} "${COMBINED}" CACHE INTERNAL "" FORCE)
endfunction()
```

The only downside is that every project needs to have an install target for this. So you need to add a dummy install command like `install(CODE "")` to projects that have no install command otherwise, e.g. those who just call `ExternalProject_Add`.