# How does CMake package finding work?

Tags: visual-c++, cmake, cinder

I was working on [Qub3d](https://qub3d.org) which uses libCinder as a dep, and kept getting this weird error about not being able to find one of the pre-bundled cmake files.

```
CMake Error at dependencies/cinder/proj/cmake/modules/cinderMakeApp.cmake:65 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "cinder" with any
  of the following names:

    cinderConfig.cmake
    cinder-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "cinder" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "cinder_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "cinder"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
```

So I looked around and found [this](http://discourse.libcinder.org/t/solved-how-to-generate-visual-studio-projects-with-cmake/927) solution, which boils down to running `cmake ..` in `(cinder_dir)/build` which somehow managed to let my project's Cmake build script to find the package `cinder`.

Does `find_package()` look for files that `cmake ..` generates?

If anyone could tell me why this works I would appreciate it very much.

Comment: If you have to manually build the `cinder` package it's not correctly integrated in `Qub3d`. If I would have to guess the project is using the `externalproject_add()` macro. Generally see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31755870/how-to-use-libraries-within-my-cmake-project-that-need-to-be-installed-first), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15175318/cmake-how-to-build-external-projects-and-include-their-targets) or more specific [CMake Running find_package after dependencies are built](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2013-October/056105.html)

Comment: actually no, its using a pre-built macro from Cinder called `ci_make_app`

Answer (score 0):

*Turning my comment into an answer*

If you have to manually build the `cinder` package it's not correctly integrated in `Qub3d` or - as `Qub3d` is using the `cinder` proposed way of integration - a bug in `cinder` library's CMake support.

Looking at the [`ci_make_app()`](https://github.com/cinder/Cinder/blob/master/proj/cmake/modules/cinderMakeApp.cmake#L59) code [you were referring to](https://github.com/qub3d/qub3dengine/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L31), the `find_package()` call will only work if `cinder` is already build ([generating the needed `cinderConfig.cmake`](https://github.com/cinder/Cinder/blob/master/proj/cmake/libcinder_target.cmake#L115)).

**How does it work?**

See the  [documentation of the `find_package()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html) for the details on the "search algorithm". In case of `cinder` the `PATH` argument simply points to where to find the `cinderConfig.cmake` file.

You can see what CMake's `find_package()` is doing by using `cmake -D CMAKE_FIND_DEBUG_MODE=ON ..`

**References**

- [Cinder's CMake documentation](https://libcinder.org/docs/branch/master/guides/cmake/cmake.html)

Comment: This is what the person in the link I gave did to fix his problem: `Apologies, this works just fine! I missed the argument in one of the cmake commands. So you run “cmake -G"Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64” …" from CINDER_PATH/build and then again from your project proj/cmake/build folder. If errors you may need to delete the contents of the build folder if something was there previous.`