# CMake build and install shared library from subdirectory before building main directory

Tags: cmake

Here is my source code structure:

```
cd my_git_repo/
    CMakeLists.txt
    src/
        main.cpp
        mylibrary/
            a.hpp
            b.hpp
            a.cpp
            b.cpp
            CMakeLists.txt
```

Root `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project(myexe CXX)
add_subdirectory(src/mylibrary)

find_library(mylib NAMES mylibrary.so PATHS "./src/mylibrary/mylibrary.so")
add_executable(myexe src/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(myexe ${mylib})
```

`mylibrary/CMakeLists.txt` is very simple. It builds a shared library and installs them.
Ideally, `mylibrary` target should be built and **installed** before `myexe` is built. But this doesn't happen. `mylibrary` is built followed by `myexe`. Installation happens later. Because of this, `find_library` fails. `pkg_check_modules()` works for other shared libraries but fails here because of the same reason.

I appreciate your help.

Edit:
This question differs from the duplicate because the answers posted to that question seem to be statically linking the library `target_link_libraries(game engine)`. I want to dynamically link the `.so` library.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use libraries within my CMake project that need to be installed first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31755870/how-to-use-libraries-within-my-cmake-project-that-need-to-be-installed-first)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea in CMake is to build *modules* and then link them together.

You haven't shared the `CMakeLists.txt` for my library, so we cannot tell what it is doing. However, assuming that it is something like:

```
ADD_LIBRARY(mylibrary
  file1.cpp
  file2.cpp
)
```

Since you specified that you want `mylibrary` to always be linked as shared, you need to tell CMake that as well by either setting `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS` TO `ON` or by specifying `SHARED` in [`add_library`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html):

```
ADD_LIBRARY(mylibrary SHARED
  file1.cpp
  file2.cpp
)
```

This is your library module. We will keep it simple for now and not worry about packing the library archive and installation here.

Now, back to your main `CMakeLists.txt` and how to make `myexe` consume it. Since you have already `add_subdirectory(src/mylibrary)`, CMake knows about `mylibrary`. So simply link it using the module name. There is no need to `find_library` as you have already defined the module.

```
add_executable(myexe src/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(myexe mylibrary)
```

This should suffice.

Do note, however, this is a very basic example to explain to you how CMake is designed to work. If you aren't building the library, and it is already installed, you would call `find_library`. Modern CMake is a bit more sophisticated and uses [generator expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html), so be sure to read up on that as you progress to more complex projects.

Comment: Yes, `mylibrary` CMakeLists.txt is very simple. It does `add_library(mylibrary SHARED blah)`.  I did try `target_link_libraries(myexe mylibrary)` and it worked. But, does it do dynamic linking? Looks like the library is statically linked which I am trying to avoid.

Comment: Just set the cache variable [BUILD_SHARED_LIBS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/BUILD_SHARED_LIBS.html) to on.

Comment: Yes, as @havogt mentions, you can set `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS` to `ON`, or you can specify that the `mylibrary` module is always built and linked as a shared library by changing add_library to `ADD_LIBRARY(mylibrary SHARED
  file1.cpp
  file2.cpp
)`

Comment: @psy You asked me to answer this but what's above is the correct answer. Let us know if it still doesn't work.